# unexpected end of app after method onKeyDown

Tags: android, listview, view, back

hi guys after i call the method onKeyDown and my app closes without get me back error, this my code:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
  {
      if (expList.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
          expList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

      }else{
          //
      }

  }
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: So there is no exception in LogCat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your app closes because you call the method "super.onKeyDown(keycode, event);"

Try in using a return false like this :

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
      {
          if (expList.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
              expList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

          }else{
              //
          }

      }
      return false;
    }
```